# Is it possible to use Content-Security-Policy to allow inline scripts from one host, but only external scripts from other hosts?

Tags: content-security-policy

Is it possible to use Content-Security-Policy to allow inline scripts from one host, but only external scripts from other hosts?

I'd like to do something like:

`Header set Content-Security-Policy script-src myhost.com 'unsafe-inline'; script-src someothersite.com`

But obviously that's invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use Content-Security-Policy to allow inline scripts from one host, but only external scripts from other hosts?

No, it’s not possible. Content Security Policy (by design) lacks any means to express that.

In particular, as far as CSP syntax goes, `myhost.com` and `'unsafe-inline'` are both what the CSP spec calls a *“source expression”*, and the value of the `script-src` CSP directive is what the CSP spec calls a *“source list”* — that is, a list of separate individual source expressions.

And in a CSP source list, source expressions have no relation internally with each other — instead they each apply to the entire directive they’re part of. So if you specify `'unsafe-inline'` for the value of a `script-src` directive, then that always has the effect of globally allowing inline scripts anywhere in the document, period.

So the gist of it is: CSP has no syntax to express *“only allow inline scripts for `myhost.com`”*.

---

The spec details are at https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#framework-directive-source-list:

> Many directives' values consist of ***source lists***: sets of strings which identify content that can be fetched and potentially embedded or executed. Each string represents one of the following types of ***source expression***:
>
> 1. Keywords such as `'none'` and `'self`' (which match nothing and the current URL’s origin, respectively)
> 2. Serialized URLs such as `https://example.com/path/to/file.js` (which matches a specific file) or `https://example.com/` (which matches everything on that origin)
> 3. Schemes such as `https:` (which matches any resource having the specified scheme)
> 4. Hosts such as `example.com` (which matches any resource on the host, regardless of scheme) or `*.example.com` (which matches any resource on the host’s subdomains (and any of its subdomains' subdomains, and so on))
> 5. Nonces such as `'nonce-ch4hvvbHDpv7xCSvXCs3BrNggHdTzxUA'` (which can match specific elements on a page)
> 6. Digests such as `'sha256-abcd...'` (which can match specific elements on a page)